# Fluxor breaks ErrorBoundary in Blazor Wasm

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0, fluxor

I'm having a problem where the error page of ErrorBoundary does not show when using Fluxor in Blazor wasm 8.

I think this is because the exception is caught during control render sequence.
So when Using

> Dispatcher.Dispatch(action)

and an exception occurs, I get

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
  Unhandled exception rendering component: Exception of type 'MyApp.Errors.ServerValidationException'
```

and I get

> An unhandled error has occurred. Reload

message and the error page of the ErroBounday is NOT shown.

But if I don't use Fluxor and only do a classic service call, the error page of the ErrorBoundary is show.

Is there a way to fix this?